# flutter moor query filter with date

Tags: flutter, flutter-moor

I want to get a stream of record which are in the same day of input (like all records with date of Feb 23, 2020).

```
Stream<List<BloodSugar>> watchBloodSugarsInDate(DateTime date) {

    return (select(bloodSugarsEntity)
          ..where((bp) => bp.date.equals(date)))
        .map((bloodSugarsEntity) => convertEntityToModel(bloodSugarsEntity))
        .watch();
  }
```

this is my code and it doesn't work because dateTime is combine of date and time. I tried using nested queries for separated comparison of year, month and day but I couldn't make it.
Any help would be much appriciated.

Comment: take a look on this https://github.com/simolus3/moor/issues/304

Comment: thanks. I update my method to this but it still doesn't work

  Stream<List<BloodSugar>> watchBloodSugarsInDate(DateTime dateTime) {

    return (select(bloodSugarsEntity)
        ..where((row) {
          final asDate = FunctionCallExpression('date', [row.date]);
          final year = FunctionCallExpression<String, StringType>(
              'strftime', [const Constant<String, StringType>('%Y'), asDate]);
          final month = FunctionCallExpression<String, StringType>(
              'strftime', [const Constant<String, StringType>('%m'), asDate]);

Comment: final day = FunctionCallExpression<String, StringType>(
            'strftime',  [const Constant<String, StringType>('%d'), asDate]);


          return year.equals(dateTime.year.toString()) & month.equals(dateTime.month.toString()) & day.equals(dateTime.day.toString());
        }))
        .map((bloodSugarsEntity) => convertEntityToModel(bloodSugarsEntity))
        .watch();
  }

Comment: what is the value of `date` ?

Comment: do you mean dateTime? there is no date in the function

Comment: I mean the value of the parameter

Comment: a DateTime instance like DateTime.now()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  bool isSameDate(bp) {
    final value = bp.date;

    return value.year == date.year &&
        value.month == date.month &&
        value.day == date.day;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get `date` from your `row`, and just compare with passed `searchDate`.

You have to compare `year` with `year`, `month` with `month` and `day` with `day`:

```
Stream<List<BloodSugar>> watchBloodSugarsInDate(DateTime searchDate) {
  return (select(bloodSugarsEntity)
        ..where(
          (row) {
            final date = row.date;

            return date.year.equals(searchDate.year) &
                date.month.equals(searchDate.month) &
                date.day.equals(searchDate.day);
          },
        ))
      .map((bloodSugarsEntity) => convertEntityToModel(bloodSugarsEntity))
      .watch();
}
```